# Should I use a Constructor or init function in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

There is a class B has Class A member m_a

```
class A{
    A(...);
    ~A();
    init(...);
    ...//other methods;
    ...//data
    }
```

in order to initialize m_a with certain value, I could use the constructor or the init() function.
If I use constructor, and the value can't be decide in the class B constructor, I would have to use a `A* m_a` and `new A(...)` to initialize later.
Or if I use init() function, I could just use `A a` as the member of the B class.
So in this case is init() function is a better way of doing it?

Comment: Go and find out information on *member initialization list*

Comment: An `init` function becomes available to `friend`s of the class. If that doesn't impact your design, go ahead.

Answer (score 6):

You should prefer initializing all members either in constructors, or inline (directly where you declare them) unless you have a *good* reason not to.

If you use `init`-style functions for that, you are opening up the possibility of using objects that have not been initialized.

I would suggest making it impossible to instantiate a B object without knowing what value `m_a` should have. To do that, you should use a constructor for `B` that takes an `A` argument:

```
class B {
public:
    explicit B(A a)
        : m_a(std::move(a))
    { }

private:
    A m_a;
};
```

This way, it is impossible to create a `B` object without knowing what `m_a` should be initialized with:

```
B b; // error
```

Users of `B` are forced to provide a value for `B::m_a` and thus can't end up using an uninitialized `B` object:

```
B b(A());
```

If you wonder what the `std::move` is about, it allows to move the `a` argument into the `m_a` member without copying, which is faster. To read more about it, search for "C++ move semantics". However, this is optional and not required for the above example to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your pb, but definitively I will go for constructor.

```
struct A{
    A(int a = 0):a_(a);{}
    a_:
}

struct B{
    B(int b = 0):A_(b);{}
    A_ get_A(){ return A_;}
    A A_
}
```

After if you need a function to update the init I will create a free function

```
void foo(A& a){
     //whatever 
}
```

then a method of B return A_ and use foo

```
B b;
foo(b.get_A());
```

It is one possible method. Keep in mind C++ constructor init value and a least give a default value usually 0. My 2 cents, hope it helps

Tim

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple constructors that all require the same initialization code, putting that code in an `init` function can reduce redundancy and bugs as the class is modified. Otherwise it makes more sense for the constructor to be complete by itself.

There are certain constructs that *can't* be initialized outside of the initialization list of a constructor, such as `const` or reference members. For those you will have no choice except to initialize them in each constructor.

Comment: Would such an `init` method be better private and called by the constructor?

Comment: Although with delegating constructors and in-line member initializers there is less of a need for dedicated init functions.